# pivot_wider when names_from are duplicated

Tags: r

I need help pivoting data and then removing unnecessary rows. I ran a query in SQL that returned a rather large output (60 columns and 2 million rows). A lot of the rows are near duplicates, with the only unique value coming from a "diagnosis" column. I would like to pivot those to new columns and then remove the duplicates. The wrinkle is that my names_from column has duplicates. Here is an example

```
id <- c("1","1","1","2","2","2")
priority <- c("primary","secondary","tertiary","primary","primary","secondary")
diagnosis <- c("depression","anxiety","anorexia","depression","anxiety","ptsd")

data <- data.frame(id,priority,diagnosis)
```

| id | priority | diagnosis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | primary | depression |
| 1 | secondary | anxiety |
| 1 | tertiary | anorexia |
| 2 | primary | depression |
| 2 | primary | anxiety |
| 2 | secondary | PTSD |

When I try to pivot_wider, person 2 has both depression and anxiety listed in "primary", but I want them in separate columns.

```
data2 <- pivot_wider(data,names_from=priority,values_from = diagnosis)
```

Here is what it is showing me:

| id | primary | secondary | tertiary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | depression | anxiety | anorexia |
| 2 | c("depression,"anxiety") | ptsd | NULL |

So how can I get it to separate out depression and anxiety for person 2, ideally into something like primary_1, primary_2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a sequence by 'id', 'primary' and then do the reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
data %>% 
  mutate(priority = str_c(priority, '_', rowid(id, priority))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = priority, values_from = diagnosis)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  id    primary_1  secondary_1 tertiary_1 primary_2
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>    
1 1     depression anxiety     anorexia   <NA>     
2 2     depression ptsd        <NA>       anxiety
```

---

Or another option is to return the `list` and then use `unnest_wider` on the `list` columns

```
data %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = priority, values_from = diagnosis,
    values_fn = list) %>%
   unnest_wider(where(is.list), names_sep = "_")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  id    primary_1  primary_2 secondary_1 tertiary_1
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>       <chr>     
1 1     depression <NA>      anxiety     anorexia  
2 2     depression anxiety   ptsd        <NA>
```

---

If we need to rename with 1, 2 only when the lengths are greater than 1, do the `unnest` separately after using `unnest_wider`

```
data %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = priority, values_from = diagnosis,
    values_fn = list) %>% 
   unnest_wider(where(~ is.list(.x) && max(lengths(.x)) > 1),  
         names_sep = "_") %>% 
   unnest(where(is.list))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  id    primary_1  primary_2 secondary tertiary
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   
1 1     depression <NA>      anxiety   anorexia
2 2     depression anxiety   ptsd      <NA>
```

---

If the data is really big, then `dcast` may be more efficient

```
dcast(setDT(data), id ~ paste0(priority,  "_", rowid(id, priority)), 
   value.var = 'diagnosis')
Key: <id>
       id  primary_1 primary_2 secondary_1 tertiary_1
   <char>     <char>    <char>      <char>     <char>
1:      1 depression      <NA>     anxiety   anorexia
2:      2 depression   anxiety        ptsd       <NA>
```